# Image resize using url parmater

Tags: images

I would like to resize image in my wordpress template using url parameter. Best example for this would be Wordpress's very own [twenty Twelve theme](http://twentytwelvedemo.wordpress.com/).

Following is link to image with width parameter in the end. If you change width to 50 it'll return image with 50px width.

> https://twentytwelvedemo.files.wordpress.com/2012/03/wheat-field.jpg?w=500

I'm confused if its server setting or we can do it using php.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WordPress(.org) doesn't have anything like this built into the core. A lot of theme developers use [Timthumb](http://code.google.com/p/timthumb/) to achieve that. The example you've linked to is on a wordpress.com server so there will be something custom going on for that functionality.

You could also look at the WordPress functions add_image_size & the_post_thumbnail.